# How to create a slider which should be returned to starting position when user stop dragging and need to call method when it completes full in flutter

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-swiper

In flutter i tried with sliderTheme and slider widget but the it is working as a seek bar not as a draggable slider.

Any idea or widgets would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `slider_button` i think this package is fit your requirement very well https://pub.dev/packages/slider_button